# Finding value of $P(6)$ when $P(x)$ is a $6^{\mathrm{th}}$ degree polynomial

Tags: polynomials

$P(x)$ is a $6^{\mathrm{th}}$ degree polynomial with coefficient of $x^6$ equal to $1$. And:

> $P(1)=7$,
>
> $P(2)=10$,
>
> $P(3)=13$,
>
> $P(4)=16$,
>
> $P(5)=19$,

I have to find $P(6)$?

Comment: it will be useful if you can show your work

Comment: What is $f(x) - 3x - 4$ for the given values?

Comment: I tried using Lagrange intepolation, but since this method gives the polynomial with smallest degrees that satisfy the condition it gave me a result of:

$$f(x) = 4 + 3x\text{, which is true}$$

You may try another type of intepolation.

Answer (score 5):

A monic polynomial of degree $n$ is uniquely determined by $n$ function values.

In your case, only $5$ such values ($f(1)$, $f(2)$, $f(3)$, $f(4)$ and $f(5)$) are given, meaning that $f(6)$ can be anything. For every choice of $f(6)$, there will be a suitable monic polynomial of degree $6$ by the above property.

Answer (score 4):

Just to get you started

In this case the polynomial can be represented by"
$$
f(x)=x^{6}+a_{5}x^{5}+a_{4}x^{4}+a_{3}x^{3}+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{1}x^{1}+a_{0}
$$

Now you have 6 unknowns and 5 equations. It seems you are missing an extra information. If so, solve the system of equations to
find the coefficients. Then you have the polynomial and can just evaluate $f(6)$.

Comment: Aren't there $6$ unknowns?

Comment: @Alraxite, you are right, for some reason I did forget to count the constant term.

Answer (score 3):

As @Stefan4024 has remarked the first degree polynomial $p_0(x):=3x+4$ realizes the given values. The polynomial $q(x):=P(x)-p_0(x)$ should therefore be of degree  $6$, have highest coefficient $1$, and should vanish at $1$,$2$, $\ldots$, $5$. Such a $q$ is necessarily of the form
$$q(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-c)$$
for some $c\in{\mathbb R}$ (or $\in{\mathbb C}$). It follows that the most general $P$ satisfying your conditions is given by
$$P(x)=3x+4+(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-c)\ .$$
We now compute
$$P(6)=18+4+5! (6-c)=742-120 c$$
and can immediately verify that the value $P(6)$ can yet be anything.

Comment: plz see what is wrong in my method?

Comment: @Ankesh: Your $h$ is not the most general polynomial of degree $6$ having the five given zeros, because you forced the sixth zero to be at $0$, not at a general $c$.

Comment: okay i got your point. but if we get to know the f(0) value then my solution is write as we can take x instead of x-c? am i right?

Answer (score 2):

I tried like this only:
$$
742.
$$
**Explanation**: Since the function value is in A.P. (i.e $7,10,13,16,19$), the $n$-th term is:
$$
7+(n-1)3=3n+4
$$
Leading coefficient is given as $1$. Now let polynomial be $h(x)=f(x)-(3x+4)$ which is also of degree $6$.

So that $h(x)$ will always be $0$ for $x=1$ to $5$. So $1,2,3,4,5$ are factors of $f(x)$. So it is roots of $h(x)$:
$$
h(x)=1\cdot x(x−1)(x−2)(x−3)(x−4)(x−5)
$$
$$
h(6)=1\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1=720
$$
$$
f(6)=h(6) + (3\cdot6 +4)\to f(6)=720+22=742
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let f(x) be the ponomial P(x) - x^6.
Then f(1) = 7 - 1^6 = 6
f(2) = 10 - 2^6 = -54
f(3) = 13 - 3^6 = -716
f(4) = 16 - 4^6 = -4080
f(5) = 19 - 5^6 = -15606

A 4th degree ponomial determined by these points is -140x^4+1050x^3-3101x^2+3993x-1796.

P(6) = f(6) + 6^6 = 2542.

If you chose some coefficient for x^5 you can get any value you wish for P(6).

Comment: hi.. can you please explain how you got the 4th degree polynomial?